# Wait for child exec

Tags: c, linux, exec, fork

Short quesion:

I want wait in the parent for the child to be replaced with some exec call, **not wait for terminate**.

How can I do it?

(c language, linux platform)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch shell implementing. I want wait for background process to be executed.

Comment: You don't need to wait for the `exec`. It will happen quickly (nearly immediately)!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Even though when I got error before the `exec` it was wrote after the new `$ ` ?

Comment: What kind of errors are you expecting to get before the `exec` and after the `fork`?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch open output file to redirection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't wait in a parent for the child to do some `exec`, except by having some convention about [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), e.g. deciding to send something (in the child) on a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) just before the `exec`. You'll set up the [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) before the [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html). You might also use the Linux specific [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) for such IPC.

After the [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and before any `exec` you are running (in the child process) the same code as the parent. So it is up to you to implement such conventional communications.

BTW, generally, the child process does not do a lot of things after the `fork` and before the `exec`, so waiting for the `exec` to happen is useless.... In the unlikely case an error happens -including failure of `exec`- you just `_exit` (usually with an exit code like 127).

You might consider [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) (with `PTRACE_SYSCALL` ...) but I would not do it that way.

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and study the source code of some free software shells (`sash` or `bash`). Use also `strace` to understand what is happening in a shell.

Answer (score 2):

[Basile's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23149477/18713617) is incorrect.

While it is true that there's no real way to wait for an `exec` after a call to [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), this is not the only way to create a child process. What you can do instead is use the [vfork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) call. This will block in the parent until the child calls either `_exit` or one of the `exec` functions.

Note that part of the reason this works the way it does is that the child process from [vfork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) does not, in fact, clone the entirety of the parent's address space. This means it is undefined behaviour to modify data in the child process before `exec`. If you need to do anything weird, you may be better off with for example using [pause(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html) and installing a signal handler for `SIGUSR1` or some other signal of your choice, then using that signal immediately before the exec, or using some other IPC mechanism as mentioned above.

If you don't need to do anything special at all, and *only* want to call `fork`/`exec` right after one another, but want to be sure that execution of the child process has started, you can instead use [posix_spawn(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_spawn.3.html), which should also start an external program immediately, effectively blocking the parent until after the exec.